# How can I do to have the django-guardian reflecting on my apps in the admin panel?

Tags: python, django, django-guardian

I can see no changes with django-guardian, even using the GuardedModelAdmin. I would like that the user could see and edit only the records allowed (not just owned, but allowed) for him. But even appending all permissions the user still cannot see the rows.

[image]

```
class EventoAdmin(GuardedModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('titulo', 'ativo')
    list_editable = ('ativo',)
    readonly_fields = ('user', )
    list_display_links = ('titulo',)
    inlines = [ProdutoInline,]

    exclude = ('slug', 'onde', 'inicio', 'fim' )
    @property
    def queryset(self):
        return partial(self.get_queryset)
```

[image: What's missing?]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user also has table-level permissions, not just object-level permissions. Set table-lever permissions in the User admin.